# Looping through alphabetical pages (rvest)

Tags: css, r, web-scraping, rvest

After spending a lot of time on this problem, and looking through available answers, I wanted to go ahead and ask a new question to address the problem I have webscraping with R and rvest. I have attempted to fully lay out the problem to minimize questions

**The Problem**
I am trying to extract the author names from a conference webpage. The authors are separated alphabetically by their last name; hence, I need to use a for loop to call *follow_link()* 25 times to go to each page and extract the pertinent author text.

The conference website:
https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/authora.html

I have attempted two solutions in R using rvest, both with problems.

**Solution 1 (Letter call to link)**

```
lttrs <- LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 26 )] # create character vector
website <-  html_session(https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/authora.html)

tempList <- list() #create list to store each page's author information

for(i in 1:length(lttrs)){
  tempList[[i]] <- website %>%
  follow_link(lttrs[i])%>% #use capital letters to call links to author pages  
  html_nodes(xpath ='//*[@class = "author"]') %>% 
  html_text()  
}
```

This code works.. to a point. Below is the output. It will successfully navigate through lettered pages until the H-I transition and the L-M transition at which point it grabs the wrong page.

```
Navigating to authora.html
Navigating to authorb.html
Navigating to authorc.html
Navigating to authord.html
Navigating to authore.html
Navigating to authorf.html
Navigating to authorg.html
Navigating to authorh.html
Navigating to authora.html
Navigating to authorj.html
Navigating to authork.html
Navigating to authorl.html
Navigating to http://community.geosociety.org/gsa2016/home
```

**Solution 2 (CSS call to link)**
Using a CSS selector on the page, each lettered page is identified as an "a:nth-child(1-26)". So I reconstructed my loop using a call for that CSS identifier.

```
tempList <- list()
for(i in 2:length(lttrs)){
  tempList[[i]] <- website %>%
    follow_link(css = paste('a:nth-child(',i,')',sep = '')) %>%
    html_nodes(xpath ='//*[@class = "author"]') %>% 
    html_text()
}
```

This works *kindof*. Again it has trouble with certain transitions (see below)

```
Navigating to authora.html
Navigating to uploadlistall.html
Navigating to http://community.geosociety.org/gsa2016/home
Navigating to authore.html
Navigating to authorf.html
Navigating to authorg.html
Navigating to authorh.html
Navigating to authori.html
Navigating to authorj.html
Navigating to authork.html
Navigating to authorl.html
Navigating to authorm.html
Navigating to authorn.html
Navigating to authoro.html
Navigating to authorp.html
Navigating to authorq.html
Navigating to authorr.html
Navigating to authors.html
Navigating to authort.html
Navigating to authoru.html
Navigating to authorv.html
Navigating to authorw.html
Navigating to authorx.html
Navigating to authory.html
Navigating to authorz.html
```

Specifically, this method misses B,C, and D. Looping to the incorrect pages at this step. I would greatly appreciate any insights or directions for how my above code could be reconfigured to correctly loop through all 26 alphabetical pages.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO (and kudos on a  first question).

You seem to have gotten *super lucky* as the [`robots.txt`](https://gsa.confex.com/robots.txt) for that site has a ton of entries but doesn't try to restrict what you're doing.

We can pull all of the `href`s in the alphabet pagination links at the bottom of the page with `html_nodes(pg, "a[href^='author']")`. Below grabs all the paper links from all the authors:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

pg <- read_html("https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/authora.html")

html_nodes(pg, "a[href^='author']") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  sprintf("https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/%s", .) %>% 
  { pb <<- progress_estimated(length(.)) ; . } %>%  # we'll use a progress bar as this will take ~3m
  map_df(~{

    pb$tick()$print() # increment progress bar

    Sys.sleep(5) # PLEASE leave this in. It's rude to hammer a site without a crawl delay

    read_html(.x) %>% 
      html_nodes("div.item > div.author") %>% 
      map_df(~{
        data_frame(
          author = html_text(.x, trim = TRUE),
          paper = html_nodes(.x, xpath="../div[@class='papers']/a") %>% 
            html_text(trim = TRUE),
          paper_url = html_nodes(.x, xpath="../div[@class='papers']/a") %>% 
            html_attr("href") %>% 
            sprintf("https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/%s", .)
        )
      })
  }) -> author_papers

author_papers
## # A tibble: 34,983 x 3
##    author               paper  paper_url                                                    
##    <chr>                <chr>  <chr>                                                        
##  1 Aadahl, Kristopher   296-5  https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/Paper283542.html
##  2 Aanderud, Zachary T. 215-11 https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/Paper286442.html
##  3 Abbey, Alyssa        54-4   https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/Paper281801.html
##  4 Abbott, Dallas H.    341-34 https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/Paper287404.html
##  5 Abbott Jr., David M. 38-6   https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/Paper278060.html
##  6 Abbott, Grant        58-7   https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/Paper283414.html
##  7 Abbott, Jared        29-10  https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/Paper286237.html
##  8 Abbott, Jared        317-9  https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/Paper282386.html
##  9 Abbott, Kathryn A.   187-9  https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/Paper286127.html
## 10 Abbott, Lon D.       208-16 https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/Paper280093.html
## # ... with 34,973 more rows
```

I don't know what you need off of the individual paper pages so you can do that.

You also don't have to wait ~3m since the the `author_papers` data frame is in this RDS file: https://rud.is/dl/author-papers.rds which you can read with:

```
readRDS(url("https://rud.is/dl/author-papers.rds"))
```

If you *do* plan on scraping 34,983 papers then please continue to heed to "don't be rude" and use a crawl delay (ref: https://rud.is/b/2017/07/28/analyzing-wait-delay-settings-in-common-crawl-robots-txt-data-with-r/).

**UPDATE**

```
html_nodes(pg, "a[href^='author']") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  sprintf("https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2016AM/webprogram/%s", .) %>% 
  { pb <<- progress_estimated(length(.)) ; . } %>%  # we'll use a progress bar as this will take ~3m
  map_df(~{

    pb$tick()$print() # increment progress bar

    Sys.sleep(5) # PLEASE leave this in. It's rude to hammer a site without a crawl delay

    read_html(.x) %>% 
      html_nodes("div.item > div.author") %>% 
      map_df(~{
        data_frame(
          author = html_text(.x, trim = TRUE),
          is_presenting = html_nodes(.x, xpath="../div[@class='papers']") %>% 
            html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% # retrieve the text of all the "papers"
            paste0(collapse=" ") %>% # just in case there are multiple nodes we flatten them into one
            grepl("*", ., fixed=TRUE) # make it TRUE if we find the "*" 
        )
      })
  }) -> author_with_presenter_status

author_with_presenter_status
## # A tibble: 22,545 x 2
##    author               is_presenting
##    <chr>                <lgl>        
##  1 Aadahl, Kristopher   FALSE        
##  2 Aanderud, Zachary T. FALSE        
##  3 Abbey, Alyssa        TRUE         
##  4 Abbott, Dallas H.    FALSE        
##  5 Abbott Jr., David M. TRUE         
##  6 Abbott, Grant        FALSE        
##  7 Abbott, Jared        FALSE        
##  8 Abbott, Kathryn A.   FALSE        
##  9 Abbott, Lon D.       FALSE        
## 10 Abbott, Mark B.      FALSE        
## # ... with 22,535 more rows
```

Which you can also retrieve with:

```
readRDS(url("https://rud.is/dl/author-presenter.rds"))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It may be doing a bit more than I need.  All I need to do is collect all of the author names from each page from the 2016 conference. Perhaps this does a bit more than I need in terms of scraping. However, I was able to clean up the dataframe with unique() as there are multiple counts of authors who are listed on multiple abstracts.

Comment: Ah one more question, if I wanted to note whether or not someone was the presenting author, denoted with an * in the page. Would there be a simply solution to create a new column of True/False for presenting status?

Comment: Updated to just get the author and whether they were a presenter.

Comment: Woohoo Thanks so much! I really appreciate it :)